# ...qu'il n'eût tenu qu'à lui de lire dans le cœur de

Tags: grammaire, traduction

Sentences in Stendhal's *Le Rouge et le Noir* can be difficult to read sometimes.

The syntax of this one is baffling.

"*et leur succès l'occupait beaucoup plus que le sentiment de préférence marquée qu'il n'eût tenu qu'à lui de lire dans le cœur de madame de Rênal.*"

(Chapter 7, p. 93 Folio classique)

I can't find a matching form in the dictionary for

"*qu'il n'eût tenu qu'à lui*".

The closest I could find was *ça ne tient qu'à lui* which translates as  "it is entirely up to him".

But that doesn't seem to match because the subject is "il" (Julien?), not "ça".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the pronoun

> qu'**il** n'eût tenu qu'à lui

Is impersonal like in

> Il est 10h.
>
> It's 10 o'clock.

So your translation was correct, you can translate it by *It*.

> It is entirely up to him.

Comment: I see. And the que in qu'il would be the object of lire and would stand for le sentiment. I'm happy with that answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Glad I could help ;)

Comment: Note that ***ça** ne tient qu'à lui* is less formal than the literary ***il** ne tient qu'à lui*.

Answer (score 1):

Another manner of expressing nearly the same idea as *qu'il n'eût tenu qu'à lui* is

> [...] qu'il n'incomba qu'à lui [...]

Comment: That would be *[...] qu'il n'eût incombé qu'à lui [...]*, but *incomber* implies a responsibility, a duty which would make no sense in Stendhal's sentence where *tenir* is about Julien Sorel's own volition.

Comment: Oui je sais @jlliagre. D'où le *nearly* soit dit en passant. Aussi, je ne sais pas de ce qu'il en est en Anglais, mais *incomber* ***peut*** s'employer dans ce cas ci. Cela n'implique ***pas nécessairement*** la notion de responsabilisation dans sa forme la plus forte. J'en veux pour preuve (toute  relative) l'existence d'une expression consacrée bien connue des francophones: *être tenu responsable de...*

Comment: 1: Utiliser le passé simple au lieu de l'imparfait du subjonctif introduit un contresens. 2: *...et leur succès l'occupait beaucoup plus que le sentiment de préférence marquée qu'il n'eût incombé qu'à lui de lire dans le cœur de madame de Rênal.* est improbable. Google ngrams ne trouve aucune occurrence de *il n'eût incombé*, *il n'a incombé* ou *il n'incomba*. Seul le présent semble se rencontrer (*le sentiment de préférence marquée qu'il n'incombe qu'à lui de lire...*) qui, je suis d'accord, a un sens assez proche. 3: Cette réponse n'en étant pas une, il aurait fallu l'écrire en commentaire.

Comment: J'en retiens @jlliagre que nous sommes d'accord. Puis google fait bien ce qu'il veut: le français n'est pas statique. Beaucoup de formulations (ou ngrams) restent à écrire. Pas loin d'une infinitié probablement. Non?

Comment: Oui, nous sommes d'accord sur le fait que les expressions sont proches et que la littérature n'est pas un art figé. Il n'en reste pas moins que cette réponse ne répond pas à la question et que le passage du subjonctif à l'indicatif introduit une évolution de sens peu opportune.

Answer (score -1):

You can find for instance "*[it had been due only to him](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/n%27e%C3%BBt+tenu+qu%27%C3%A0+lui)*"

Comment: `it is due to X` means either 'X has caused it' or 'it is owed to X' according to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/due). `il tient à X de...` means neither. Go home Reverso, you're drunk :)